# Oracle sysdate flexible date

Tags: oracle, sysdate

I worked this statement out

```
SELECT to_date('30.06.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy') - (LEVEL-1) DATUM 
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 366;
```

which gives me all dates from `30.06.2016` till 366 days in the past.

So far so good.

What I need to add is that `to_date('30.06.2016')` is more flexible..

What I mean I always want it to use the last day of June in sysdate + 1 year.

In this case we have 2015 at the moment - so we have 30.06.2016.

If we had 2016 I need it to use 30.06.2017.
If we had 2017 I need it to use 30.06.2018.
..
..

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT Solution**:

```
SELECT last_day(add_months(to_date('01.06.' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy'),12)) - (LEVEL-1) DATUM 
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 366
```

Comment: concatenate '30.06.' with the year. You can get the year by formatting sysdate + 365.

Comment: I corrected that - thanks horse

Comment: In order to deal properly with leap years you should do `CONNECT BY to_date('30.06.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy') - (LEVEL-1) <= ADD_MONTHS(to_date('30.06.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), -12) ` instead of `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 366;`

Comment: Your question is not the place to put your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 366 days worth of dates:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ) + INTERVAL '18' MONTH - LEVEL AS DATUM
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 366;
```

Or if you want a year's worth (365 days or 366 days in a leap year) of dates (1st July this year to 30th June next year):

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ) + INTERVAL '18' MONTH - LEVEL AS DATUM
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ) + INTERVAL '18' MONTH - LEVEL >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ) + INTERVAL '6' MONTH;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your same code, but get from sysdate the year, using to_char:

```
select to_date('30.06.'||(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')+1),'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps:

1. Truncate sysdate to the year, using Trunc().
2. Add 18 months, using Add_Months().
3. Subtract one day.